# Switching regulator question for 9 - 5v in 5v out at 2.5 amps

Tags: power, voltage-regulator

I have been looking at regulators for some time now, a couple of weeks, and I seem to be looking for something that is fairly non standard. I am taking 9v to 5v and want to out put 5v at a max of 2.5a. I would like the cut off to be as low as possible, like 5v, but I realize I may have to accept a vin cut off of 7v.

I think I have found a circuit that will produce the values I want (9-5v in and 5v out at 2.5 amps with drop off at 7vin) I'm just a little curious as to what some of the sub scripts on the equations mean. The diagram is at the top of the page 14 in http://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM340.pdf . What values should I, how would I find, to plug in to solve for Rsc and R1?

I believe this is the solution I'm looking for. If there are any glaring reasons that this will not work like I want but am missing, I appreciate the heads up.

Comment: Your question is tagged `switching-regulator` but the LM340 is a linear regulator. As BarsMonster says, you probably really do need a switching regulator.

Comment: Your tags and title don't match the content. The LM340/78XX series are linear not switching regulators, and the arduino isn't relevant even if that is your application for this supply.

Comment: I retagged the original question as per these comments.

Comment: How about an achieveable min input voltage.  Do you really need down to 5 V input to 5 V output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regulator solution for 5 volts at +2ish amps](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10538/regulator-solution-for-5-volts-at-2ish-amps)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure you really want this :-)

(9-5)*2.5 = 10W power dissipation, which is manageble, but way way too hot.

I would think into DCDC step-down/up-down converters with external switch. 2.5A is easily achivable there.

You spend more on chips, save on radiators & electricity bills :-)

Comment: Thanks, that the exact kind of oversight on my part I was worried about.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simple switching regulator like the [LM2673](http://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM2673.pdf) or [LT1074](http://www.linear.com/product/LT1074) to minimize losses and headroom requirements. You should be able to get 5V at 2.5A with both of these parts without too much extra design work.